# Ajax click only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This question may have been answered already but I've checked the existing solutions and tried them with no luck. Basically, I've set up an ajax loading environment triggered by a click event but it only works for the first instance.

My js is as follows:

```
$('.load-map').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', this, function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var fileID = $(this).attr('data-level');

    $.ajax({
    url: fileID
    }).success(function (data) {
        $('#card-data').html(data);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      })}, 1000);

    });
});
```

The HTML setup is basic:

```
<a href="#" data-level="level-1.html" class="load-map level-1-marker marker current-level"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<a href="#" data-level="level-2.html" class="load-map level-2-marker marker current-level"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Comment: Try replacing `$('.load-map').each(function(){` with `$('.load-map').click(function(){` (and remove the `$(this).on('click')...`). You don't need to loop through the elements

Comment: you have the same id's of modals it can be the problem with working only once

Comment: @BrettGregson I had it as that initially and it wasn't working

Comment: @babusi does the HTML exist when the page loads or is it added later with JavaScript?

Comment: @BrettGregson, yes, it exists before

Comment: What's the timeout for? Do you want to show the modal after the ajax event?

Comment: Look at this - https://jsfiddle.net/y0cryv54/1/ Is that what you're trying to do? (the modal obviously won't open since bootstrap isn't loaded and the ajax event will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The each loop is not needed: Try this way!

```
$( document ).on('click', '.load-map', 
function(evt)
{
    var fileID = $(this).attr('data-level');

    $.ajax({
     url: fileID
     }).success(function (data) {
        $('#card-data').html(data);
     });

    setTimeout(function () {

       $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       })}, 1000);

    });
}
```